# Java try-with at complex apis

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, try-catch, try-with

I want to wrap some JDBC code into my own and different classes. So the resource is created in those classes, the result set is returned. If the client is ready, then all in that chain opened resources should be closed.

I wrote the following, but I'm not sure if that is correct enough and the easiest way.

I build a SQL string for insertion of a data-row.

From my data source (hikari pool), I get a database connection. Then I create a prepared statement, I execute this and get a `ResultSet` back.

This result set I return to the caller.

The connection and prepared statement have to remain open, until the caller is ready with that returned result set

```
public DbResult insert(int cache, String shema, String table, LinkedHashMap<String, Object> data, boolean returnAutoCreate) throws SQLException
{

//building sql-string or take it from my cache
//...

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try
    {

        connection = ds.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);

        int i = 0;
        for (Object value : data.values())
        {
            preparedStatement.setObject(i++, value);
        }

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();

        DbResult dbResult = new DbResult(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet);

        return dbResult;


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            e.addSuppressed(e2);
        }

        try
        {
            if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            e.addSuppressed(e2);
        }

        try
        {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            e.addSuppressed(e2);
        }

        throw e;

    }


}
```

Here is my DbResult class

```
class DbResult implements AutoCloseable
{

private final ResultSet rs;
private final PreparedStatement ps;
private final Connection conn;

public DbResult(Connection conn, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs)
{
    this.conn = conn;
    this.ps = ps;
    this.rs = rs;
}

@Override
public void close() throws SQLException
{

    try (conn; ps; rs;){}

}

public ResultSet getResultSet()
{
    return rs;
}

}
```

And here the client/caller-code

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ds, defaultShema);

    try(DbResult result = databaseHelper.insert(1001, defaultShema, "test", new LinkedHashMap<>(), true);)
    {
         //do sth with result
    }
```

In my insert method I added that try catch, cause if something fails there, I must close the resources.

If there is no problem, I add the resources to my `DbResult` object, and there I close the resources with the `close()`-method. In that, I use a try-with, cause if in that chain one close fails, then the others are still closed, and the exception is forwarded correctly.

At my caller, I use also a try-with, which calls that `close()`-method in DbResult after I'm done with the result.

But it's a lot of code, especially the try-catch construct in my insert-method.

I'm not sure, if there is a easier or a better way of doing that.

One more question I have:

I could cache the result, so I don't have to take care of that resource closing outside of my `DatabaseHelper` class.

There exists a `CachedRowSet`. But I'm not sure about, how expensive this is. Does that copy also the MetaInformations?

I guess the normal `ResultSet` retrieves the data first, if I access them:
the meta data, the row-data: row by row?

Is that a good idea to cache the data into ArrayList of Hashmaps?

Arraylist -> Rows
HashMap -> coloums by name -> value

So if I do that, I can close all resources immediately.
-> I don't have to care about that closing outside of my DatabaseClass
-> the pool gets the connection faster back

However, maybe I retrieve data, which I don't need (for example, the meta data).

Also, it's expensive to build a copy of my data into a ArrayList->Hashmap construct.

So what ideas do you have of that; whats the best practice?

Comment: you can use `try` with multiple `catch` for catching each specific exceptions. or may be use try-with-resource for autoclosable resource.

Comment: The `close()` methods could be wrapped with [`DbUtils.close(*)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/index.html) calls. Or, use try-with-resources. Or, use [my code](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: This sounds like something that is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, also: please don't ask multiple questions in a single question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i didnt know that, but yeah thats true, how can i move my questions to that codereview section?.... But if you have a answer to my question(s), then it would be nice too^^

Comment: @Elliiot Frisch and bekt, that dont match my question. i want to know, how to use the try-with autoclose mechanism, if i split my algorithm into different procedures (call and return flow). Is my code, i posted, correct?, Is there a better solution doing that? with the constraint, that i want retain the splitting code..... is there a better ty-catch-with-finally-close solution? Or should i change the splitting?. I thought about, to work with lambdas, so that the caller dont have to close the resources. But i dont know whats the best practice here.